# Dart Object instantiating

Tags: dart, object, instance

I'm very new to programming and Dart. I was wondering why you put `Response` in front of the variable `response`. Also why do we use `Datetime` object in front of the variable 'now?' I believe when you want to instantiate, you write `Datetime now = Datetime();` But it was written something else for the variable. What does it mean? Thank you very much in advance!

```
 void getTime() async{

    Response response = await get(Uri.parse('https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London'));
    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    // get properties from data
    String datetime = data['datetime'];
    String offset = data['utc_offset'].substring(1,3);

    //create DateTime object
    DateTime now = DateTime.parse(datetime);
    now = now.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offset)));
    print(now);

  }
```

Comment: `Response` is the type of the variable `response`. Similarly `DateTime` is the type of the variable `now`. When you declare a variable you can either specify an explicit type (such as `Response`, `DateTime`, `int`, `String` etc..) or you can declare a variable with `var` or `final` and allow type inference to determine the type for you. More information here https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#variables and here https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system#type-inference

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's break this down:

```
Response response = await 
    get(Uri.parse('https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London'));
```

A variable declaration in Dart looks like this:

```
<Type> <name> [= <value>];
```

So in your case `Response` is the type of the variable, `response` is the name of the variable and `get(Uri.parse('https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London'))` is the value of the variable (actually `get(...)` is a future, and the future's response is the value, that's why the `await` keyword is there, but that's not important.)

Sidenote, you can actually use the `var` keyword to skip the `<Type>` part of the declaration:

```
int myFunction(a, b) => a+b;

int x = myFunction(1,2);
```

Above, we know `myFunction` returns an int, and the variable `x` is equal to the result of `myFunction`, so it must also be an int, we can use the `var` keyword to skip writing int then:

```
int myFunction(a, b) => a+b;

var x = myFunction(1,2);
```

Of course, here there isn't that big a difference between writing `int` and `var`, but when your type is something like `List<Map<String, List<int>>>` it is quite nice to be able to skip writing that over and over

Now for this line:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.parse(datetime);
```

We already know that the first `DateTime` tells us what type the variable is, and we know that `now` is the name of the variable, we also know that the variable's value is `DateTime.parse(datetime)` because it is what goes after the `=` sign, but we still don't know what `DateTime.parse(datetime)` means.

Classes can have static and non-static methods, a static method is a method that gets called on a class, while a non-static method gets called on an object. Most method calls ever are non-static, look at this example:

```
class Car {
  void accelerate() {
    // some method to increase the speed of the car
  }
  
  void decelerate() {
    // some method to decrease the speed of the car
  }

  Car buyCar(int maxCost) {
    // some method to buy a new car
  }
}

void main() {
  Car car = Car();
  car.accelerate();
  car.decelerate();
  Car otherCar = car.buyCar(100000000);
}
```

Above, the method `accelerate` and `decelerate` are instance methods and that makes sense because they probably affect some statistics of the car (like current speed), `buyCar` is also an instance method, but if you think about it, it shouldn't be, it doesn't affect your current car if you buy a new one and also you shouldn't need to have a car object to buy another one in the first place. So let's make that last method static:

```
class Car {
  void accelerate() {
    // some method to increase the speed of the car
  }
  
  void decelerate() {
    // some method to decrease the speed of the car
  }

  static Car buyCar(int maxCost) {
    // some method to buy a new car
  }
}
```

It is as simple as adding the `static` keyword, now instead of having to do this:

```
Car myOldCar = Car();
Car myNewCar = myOldCar.buyCar(100000000);
```

we can just do this:

```
Car myNewCar = Car.buyCar(100000000);
```

looks familiar?

That's right `parse` is a static method on `DateTime` class, it takes a string that looks like this: `2012-02-27 13:27:00.123456789z` and returns a `DateTime` object.

So to recap:

```
Response response = await 
    get(Uri.parse('https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London'));
```

`Response` is the type of the variable, `response` is its name and `get(Uri.parse('https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London'))` is a method that returns a `Response` object.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.parse(datetime);
```

Similarly `DateTime` is the type, `now` is the name and `DateTime.parse` is a  `static` method that parses a string and makes a `DateTime` object, in this case the string is `datetime`, which was declared as being equal to `data['datetime']`.

If you want to understand better how the `parse` method works, here is the [DateTime parse documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html)